# How to tell Glassfish which OSGI bundle to use or not to use it at all

Tags: java, jar, glassfish, osgi, classloader

I try to deploy an application on Glassfish which is works fine as standalone.

This application uses some classes from library (JAR) of version v1.0.

Deployment fails with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` because VM already load this classes but another version from osgi cache bundle.

I found ready-to-use bundle with my version, but don't understand, how to use it.

Is it possible to say to VM(or mb GF )not to use bundle library or use jar-lib with required version?

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4600)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2108)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2078)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy241.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxent.__EJB31_Generated__CollectRequest__Intf____Bean__.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:411)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:128)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at com.xxent.CollectRequest$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxent.Main.collectRequest(Main.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1035)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:412)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:2048)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:431)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2613)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2005)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4082)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1200)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$000(EJBTimerService.java:89)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:1919)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.JCEMapper.init(Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)V
    at com.xxent.crypto.DigitalSignatureFactory.initXmlSec(DigitalSignatureFactory.java:221)
    at com.xxent.crypto.DigitalSignatureFactory.initDigtProvider(DigitalSignatureFactory.java:325)
    at com.xxent.crypto.DigitalSignatureFactory.init(DigitalSignatureFactory.java:62)
    at com.xxent.crypto.DigitalSignatureFactory.reinit(DigitalSignatureFactory.java:49)
    at com.xxent.CollectRequest.getRequest(CollectRequest.java:30)
    at com.xxent.CollectRequest.run(CollectRequest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4820)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:824)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:823)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:823)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4792)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4780)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 57 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are new in OSGI. Problem will be probably about classloader and bundles Import-Package (and Export-Package) setting. If you want to share class in all bundles you have to set one bundle to export it and all others to import it. Are you familliar with import/export features?

For some solution you have to tell us more information about architecture of your app. Can you post some description about affected bundles and its manifests?

Comment: You're right I'm new in OSGI. 
Actually I did not intend to use it, but it seems I'll have to(or may be not) 
Application use a lot of jar, some classes are present in osgi cache bundles in GF and use them instead of my - that's why I that's why I mention OSGI
In fact everithing I need - is to load my jar and use that classes

Comment: Well, step by step:
1. I create artifact: my-ear.ear which contains my-application.jar and a lot of lib\*.jar used by my app (also i try to place libs in \lib\appslib with the same result)
2. When I deploy it on GF - get an error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError (with all default preferences)
3. I found that VM uses class version wich is not in my libs, but in GF osgi cache bundle
4. Bungle which is used made for: glassfish5/glassfish/modules/webservices-osgi.jar
5. When I try to delete this module(and bundle) server has become bad - so I guess it's bad idea to unload it

Comment: Not shure how can I do it like comment - that's why I add stack trace to the question

Comment: It's very easy to reproduce:
In project use xmlsec-1.4.5.jar and build ear with:

`@Statless
Main.class
@Schedule(second= "*/10", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
public void doSometh() {SignatureAlgorithm.providerInit(); }`

then try to deploy to GF4 og GF5

Comment: Ok, i guess you are building your  application by maven. Right? If so, can you put it here (dependencies are interesting)?

Comment: Actually I buil it with IDE, but with Maven config. Here dependencies block:  `   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>`

Comment: Sorry for formatting, I try to find correct way to make it more readalbe

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can restrict the version of any package that you import simply by adding a range. For example if you use version 1.0 of a library package then you can add a range to your import as follows:

```
Import-Package: org.apache.xml.security.algorithms; version="[1.0, 2.0)"
```

This will prevent your code from being wired to an incorrect version of the package at runtime.

If you use modern tooling for OSGi such as bnd or one of the tools based on it (e.g. the bnd-maven-plugin or the bnd Gradle Plugin) then the import package with the correct version range will be generated for you.

Comment: Could you please claryfy how could I do it step by step?

Comment: I add to manifest lines:
    `Export-EJB: ALL
    Export-Package: com.simple; version=1.0
    Import-Package:  
    org.apache.xml.security.algorithms;version=1.4.2,com.simple; 
    version=1.0` but still have this problem

Comment: Which bundle is throwing the error? You should post the full MANIFEST.MF for that bundle.

Comment: Here is manifest for my app:
`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.simple EJB bundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.BETA
Bundle-Name: com.simple EJB bundle version 1.0.0.BETA
Export-EJB: ALL
Export-Package: com.simple; version=1.0
Import-Package: org.apache.xml.security.algorithms;version=1.4.2,com.simple; version=1.0`

Comment: when I deploy program, I check from what jar is that class loaded: bundle://314.0:1/org/apache/xml/security/algorithms/SignatureAlgorithm.class but this is wrong bundle which corresponds to: glassfish5/glassfish/modules/webservices-osgi.jar
And I have another bundle: 42.0 with correct version which is indicated in my manifest

Comment: bundle314 has manifest which contains: org.
Export-Package: apache.xml.security.algorithms;version="1.5.8" (full text is too big for comment)
bundle42 has:  Export-Package:  org.apache.xml
 .security.algorithms;version="1.4.2"

Comment: This information should be added to the original question by editing it. That will give you the space you need to lay it out readably. Also it's still not clear which bundle is attempting to actually load and use the problematic class.

Comment: You also seem to be saying that both bundle 314 and bundle 42 are exporting the `org.apache.xml.security.algorithms` package with different versions. Which version do you want to use?

Comment: Unfortunately Question is limited to 30k symbols, message with manifest has over 150k... I need to use version 1.4.2. in me application. 
When I try to cheat and delete package(org.apache...) from webservice-osgi.jar(i.e. bundle 314) application became to use library xmlsec-1.4.5.jar which is part of my EAR-file:
 jar:file:/I:/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/SimpleJAR/lib/xmlsec-1.4.5.jar!/org/apache/xml/security/algorithms/SignatureAlgorithm.class
But now it fails when I try to use WebServices

Comment: If your MANIFEST.MF is 150k long then something has gone VERY VERY wrong in your build system. Usually the manifest is no more than 20-30 lines long. How did you build this bundle?

Comment: As I said erlier, it's not my manifesf - it's manifest for prebuild bundle, which is distributed with glassfish. Real problem was that prebuilt osgi bundle was loaded by classloader of level 3 and my application with libs was load with 7-th level classloader and I still don't know the way how to avoid this(moving lib to lib\ext and setting delegate=false doesn't work) So my solution is not to use glassfish )) With WildFly it works normally